# Night Hunter vs Invisible Enemies?

Tags: league-of-legends

Further considering invisibility mechanics in League of Legends, Vayne's Night Hunter innate ability increases her move speed when moving toward an enemy.  I'm pretty sure champions beyond the fog of war are out of range, and the movement bonus no longer applies. (for instance, if someone flashes out of sight, you won't be moving faster than normal anymore)

I have not seen/heard about what happens if Vayne is running toward an invisible enemy.  Will she continue to receive a movement bonus even if she cannot see her invisible foe?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Only works if the target is visible per [this](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Vayne_The_Night_Hunter).

> Enemy champions that are not visible to Vayne (through Fog of War, brush, or stealth) will not activate Night Hunter.

Answer (score 2):

Her passive run speed increase only works if the target is visible, in front of her, and within a range of 2000. She does not gain it from invisible units until they become visible, for example she would not gain it until Temoo moves after his stealth while he is in front of her.

Comment: Ok, I get that this guy answered an already answered question a month later, but nothing he said was wrong.  He felt he had more information to add.  Regardless as to whether or not you agree he added more useful information, don't downvote a correct answer.